# Fetching millions of record from mysql database and storing all data into single array in php

Tags: php, mysql

The data is fetched completely when print in this loop

```
while($row = $this->db->fetch_assoc($result))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

This process doesnt execute when the data is stored in array

```
$arr=array();
while($row = $this->db->fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $arr[]=$row;
}
```

The process fails without error. What is the issue ?How to make it right?

Comment: do you want all data in that array or just one row

Comment: Why do you think that it fails? Do you, by any chance, putting these 2 snippets one after another?

Comment: Also shouldn't it be `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` ?

Comment: Why fails? what do you mean ..error .. wrong result?

Comment: What happens when you add `var_dump($arr)` after the second snippet?

Comment: Yes i want all data in single associative array.It contains 12 lakhs of entries with 6 columns each.These are two independent different code snippet can replaced each other.

Answer (score 0):

script may have timed out

please set

```
set_time_limit(number)
```

where number is number of seconds and try again

Comment: If script would have timed out how is it printing in loop.Plus ,I have already set.The php script in later code fails in few seconds whereas in first one it executes successfully in 5 minutes approx.
ini_set('memory_limit','1600M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);